# Integrate from JSON file and return value to it

Tags: php, json

In my linux box I am running the following php code

```
<?php
        //Get the response from the server and append timestamp data
        function get_server_response() {
                $curl_post_data = null;
                $service_url = 'http://serverip/source.php';
                $curl = curl_init($service_url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
                $response = json_decode($curl_response, true);
                curl_close($curl);
                $time = time();
                $check = $time+date("Z",$time);
                $data['timestamp'] = array('Year' => intval(strftime('%Y', $check)), 'Month' => intval(strftime('%m', $check)), 'Day' => intval(strftime('%d', $check)),
                        'Hour' => intval(strftime('%H', $check)+3), 'Minutes' => intval(strftime('%M', $check)), 'Seconds' => intval(strftime('%S', $check)));

                return array_merge($data,$response);
        }

        if (!file_exists('results.json')) {
                $response = get_server_response();
                $data = new stdClass();
                $data-> Data1 = $response;
                //Create and data to local json file
                $fp = fopen('results.json', 'a+');
                fwrite($fp, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
                fclose($fp);
        } else {
                //Read the data from existing local json file
                $file = file_get_contents("results.json");
                $data = json_decode($file);
                $object = json_decode(json_encode($data), FALSE);
                unset($file);
                //Increment based on the last object and append new key-value pair
                end($object);
                $key = key($object);
                $int = filter_var($key, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                ++$int;
                $response = get_server_response();
                $next = 'Data' . $int;
                $object-> $next = $response;
                //Update the local json file
                file_put_contents('results.json', json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        }
 ?>
```

Which outputs the following into results.json

```
{
    "Data1": {
        "timestamp": {
            "Year": 2015,
            "Month": 9,
            "Day": 14,
            "Hour": 16,
            "Minutes": 1,
            "Seconds": 36
        },
        "CG_Uptime": 199481,
        "MHS_Avg": 2661410.65,
        "MHS_5s": 3102456.1,
        "MHS_1m": 2806133.89,
        "MHS_5m": 2700647.04,
        "MHS_15m": 2720732.61,
        "MHS_Now": "2667260",
        "DegC_In": "35",
        "DegC_TopOut": "59",
        "DegC_BotOut": "61",
        "Unit_Uptime": 510403,
        "FreeMem": "403",
        "PSUVolt_Top": "233",
        "PSUVolt_Bot": "235",
        "FAN": "50",
        "VST": "612",
        "VSB": "612",
        "VMAX": "622",
        "AC_TOP": "1100",
        "AC_BOT": "1100",
        "DC_AMP": "150",
        "PSUWall_Top": "640",
        "PSUWatt_Top": "(592",
        "PSUWall_Bot": "640",
        "PSUWatt_Bot": "(596",
        "Total_Watts": 1280
    },
    "Data2": {
        "timestamp": {
            "Year": 2015,
            "Month": 9,
            "Day": 14,
            "Hour": 16,
            "Minutes": 1,
            "Seconds": 59
        },
        "CG_Uptime": 199504,
        "MHS_Avg": 2661347.27,
        "MHS_5s": 2042760.72,
        "MHS_1m": 2595202.5,
        "MHS_5m": 2657730.87,
        "MHS_15m": 2705433.81,
        "MHS_Now": "2667260",
        "DegC_In": "35",
        "DegC_TopOut": "59",
        "DegC_BotOut": "61",
        "Unit_Uptime": 510426,
        "FreeMem": "403",
        "PSUVolt_Top": "233",
        "PSUVolt_Bot": "235",
        "FAN": "50",
        "VST": "612",
        "VSB": "612",
        "VMAX": "622",
        "AC_TOP": "1100",
        "AC_BOT": "1100",
        "DC_AMP": "150",
        "PSUWall_Top": "656",
        "PSUWatt_Top": "(600",
        "PSUWall_Bot": "640",
        "PSUWatt_Bot": "(596",
        "Total_Watts": 1296
    },
    "Data3": {
        "timestamp": {
            "Year": 2015,
            "Month": 9,
            "Day": 14,
            "Hour": 21,
            "Minutes": 25,
            "Seconds": 18
        },
        "CG_Uptime": 218903,
        "MHS_Avg": 2657940.86,
        "MHS_5s": 3701517.96,
        "MHS_1m": 2658126.3,
        "MHS_5m": 2572589.83,
        "MHS_15m": 2584535.75,
        "MHS_Now": "2667260",
        "DegC_In": "34",
        "DegC_TopOut": "57",
        "DegC_BotOut": "60",
        "Unit_Uptime": 529826,
        "FreeMem": "405",
        "PSUVolt_Top": "233",
        "PSUVolt_Bot": "235",
        "FAN": "50",
        "VST": "612",
        "VSB": "612",
        "VMAX": "622",
        "AC_TOP": "1100",
        "AC_BOT": "1100",
        "DC_AMP": "150",
        "PSUWall_Top": "640",
        "PSUWatt_Top": "(596",
        "PSUWall_Bot": "624",
        "PSUWatt_Bot": "(592",
        "Total_Watts": 1264
    }
....
....
}
```

What I want to do is to add an extra field in the JSON file (named "Total_KWh"), that calculates the total Kilowatt-hours. In other words, to integrate the "Total_Watts" value over time and add the results to each json block. The calculation would be incremental to save cpu.
So at "Data1" I start with "Total_KWh":0 then on "Data2" I calculate the time difference in hours (in this case, 23 seconds which is 0.006388 hours), then I multiply with "Total_Watts" value from Data2 and I would get the new "Total_KWh" value.
So in this example, "Total_KWh" would be 0.006388*1.296 = 0.00827.
Can you help me modify the php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to add an extra item "timestamp_raw" to every Data* block for calculating time difference between every next pair in Data* set:

```
function get_server_response() {
...
curl_close($curl);
$time = time();
$check = $time+date("Z",$time);
$data['timestamp_raw'] = $check;
...
}
```

Then, we can get through in such way:

```
...
    $key = key($object);
    $int = filter_var($key, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    ++$int;
    $response = get_server_response();
    $next = 'Data' . $int;
    $response["Total_KWh"] = number_format(($response["timestamp_raw"] - $obj->$key->timestamp_raw)/60/60, 6) * ($response["Total_Watts"]/1000);
    $object->$next = $response;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added the code but I get values for Total_KWh around 500, no matter the time difference, which make no sense...

Comment: Ok found the problem, had to use $object instead of $obj.. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there was just another variable name. I'm glad you found it. Good luck! )

Comment: One more thing. In order to find the Total_KWh for Data(n), the code should multiply the Total_Watts(n) with the time difference between Data(n) and Data(n-1) and add it to Total_Watts(n-1). This code seems to just multiply the Total_Watts(n) with the time difference between Data(n) and Data(1) instead (the first value). How can i fix it?

Comment: what do mean Data(1) ? Every time you call get_server_response() function the code compares its response with last previous Data block.
What is the main goal? Is it to totalize the amount of kWatts for all time ranges or to check the difference in consuming watts through time intervals?

Comment: The purpose of "Total_KWh" is to totalize the amount of kWatts for all time ranges. So I should add previous value to a total sum. How should I change the code to accomplish that?